# Keycloak token not recognized when switching for spring-boot 2.4.7 to 2.5.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, keycloak

I have a simple application working with spring boot 2.4.7 that does not work with spring-boot 2.5.1

The new version does not recognized the token provided by my keycloak instance (v 12.0.4)

In debug mode on the server log , i have only the message "Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid" :

```
2021-06-16 13:33:18,789 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy : Securing GET /
2021-06-16 13:33:18,792 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2021-06-16 13:33:18,796 DEBUG org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters : Set encoding to UTF-8
2021-06-16 13:33:18,808 DEBUG org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider : Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid
2021-06-16 13:33:18,812 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
```

One the client side , i have the following log:

```
< HTTP/1.1 401 
< WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Malformed payload", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

Is there a way to have more information ?

Here is the code for authentication config :

```
package test;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;


@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    
    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        configureCommon(http);
        http
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();
    }

    public static void configureCommon(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                  .authenticated()
        ;
                
    }

}
```

Build configuration (gradle) :

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.1'
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management' 


repositories { 
    mavenCentral() 
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}


//create a single Jar with all dependencies
jar {
    archiveBaseName = 'jwtTest'
    archiveVersion =  '0.1.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose"
}
```

Configuration of the ressource server (keycloak server)  using jwk-set-uri :

```
server:
  port: 8090
spring:
  application:
    name: externalApp 
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:89/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

Here is the token that is valid according to jwt.io  :

eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJSbXFOVTNLN0x4ck5SRmtIVTJxcTZZcTEya1RDaXNtRkw5U2NwbkNPeDBjIn0.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.CZBPu7DUBzMoePaaTTmholKo0_W0r3Q9ov1lweuPeTiYZMUT2mLI7LiMzqJX0lRcgVdvWAJUxrlRwL1v4ikvYwXcV7MkdH-BauDdXd2xkIYXyWb1AulmqUHKmiRFLuPwbiTrLBfy1bRuFM7VcOxUN0IZpLI6dVllSq26aoAMR8iO_5dSynlNlUf3_utZLX1R26y85Sj9SoJXe1UheYJnLX2c-tI6iDZ29_YRzGhaF3a1oIauLyIOTmBoApBv_PMJFtyGAD_15b56luZ8fAHKBNvRlC_NnXt9EBwKpPxywgdP9yLMHjMDSWYTGhVfgWGoO-ihQql8D57-S9nPapHcbA

With log in TRACE mode :

```
2021-06-17 09:20:51,029 TRACE org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager : Authenticating request with JwtAuthenticationProvider (1/2)
2021-06-17 09:20:51,042 TRACE org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder : Failed to process JWT
com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.BadJWTException: Payload of JWS object is not a valid JSON object
        at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.extractJWTClaimsSet(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:286)
        at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:379)
        at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.createJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:154)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.decode(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:137) 
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:97)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:88)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:130)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)        
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Payload of JWS object is not a valid JSON object
        at com.nimbusds.jwt.SignedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet(SignedJWT.java:98)
        at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.extractJWTClaimsSet(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:283)
        ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Comment: If you change the logging level to trace, you can get more information about the exception that was thrown. Look for logs that start with `Failed to process JWT`.

Comment: It says me that's the token is not valid json , but it is well decode by jwt.io ...

Answer (score 2):

Update com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:9.8.1 to 9.10 solve the problem

add in gradle.build :

```
implementation "com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:9.10"
```

Comment: can you explain more about this solution? I have the same problem but don't know why

Comment: I add to force the use of a more recent version of nimbus-jose-jwt . In the meantime i migrate to spring-boot 2.5.2 and i do not have the problem anymore